# Django Rest Framework and permissions

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, django-rest-framework

I've read through a couple of StackOverflow threads yet but couldn't come to any satisfying nor a working solution.
I'd like to have several custom permissions, whom are more or less complex (varying from ReadOnly to, limit by-user ...).

Let's start out with what I have right now:

- a base class, ReadOnly
- my settings
- a viewset for users.
- and a staff_user, who let's collapse everything

My base class looks like:

```
class ReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Only, always, ever allow read-only access.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return False
```

and is accordingly innerhited by the example user's viewset

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    Retrieve the user associated with your session and allow all methods.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (ReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id) # This should return an empty queryset when not logged in
```

And the appropriate fall-back default permission is

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'api.permissions.ReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

When I now access the users page and log in as a staff I can just easily create users via POST and same applies for all my other viewsets. What happens here?

Comment: The code you pasted here *does* work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've gut a bit further on the issue..
So, here's my code for a more complex permission:

```
class IsCurrentUserOrDeny(permissions.BasePermission):
"""
Allow the current user to edit his own user object
"""

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    return False
    if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
        return obj == request.user

    return False

def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return True
```

Apparently, using the ModelViewSet will not look up the has_object_permissions method. Changing the has_permissions to False denies all requests (as expected). The documentation tells

> Note: The instance-level has_object_permission method will only be called if the view-level has_permission checks have already passed. Also note that in order for the instance-level checks to run, the view code should explicitly call .check_object_permissions(request, obj). If you are using the generic views then this will be handled for you by default.

Since ModelViewSet is a composed class that inerhits from GenericViewApi, the expected behavior would be:

- Check wether has_permissions returns True
- => Check wether has_object_permissions returns True

But this is not actually the case. What's wrong here?